# Problemas al instalar composer

Tags: php, composer

Estoy instalando composer en mi pc y me da el siguiente error

> The APP_DATA or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for
>   composer to run correctly.

Tengo *xampp* con la version 7.2, pero no se que variable de entorno, tengo que configurar.

La instalación de ese mismo programa la hice en otra pc y sí funcionó.

La instalación la estoy haciendo en *windows 7*

Agradecería su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

En tu línea de comandos escribe:

```
SET COMPOSER_HOME="C:\ruta\a\composer"
```

Y luego realiza un self-update de composer.

```
composer self-update
```